# Laplace transform of Heaviside function - question about substitution of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I was looking at Haberman's book on ODEs, and it is pretty good. But one confusing point has to do with this example of using the Laplace transform on a Heavyside function. I am not clear on how the $\tau$ versus $t$ substitution occurs. Here is the example from the book.

[image]

So I marked the question area in red. I understand that the original function must be expressed in the form of $f(t-c)H(t-c)$. So that means converting the function $t^2$ into a function in terms of $t-1$ where $c=1$. But the substitutions seem a bit so in the first red line, the function is setup at $f(t-1) = t^2$, but that is not accurate since $f(t-1) = (t-1)^2$. So this might be a notational lack of clarity, but it seems confusing to me. The issue carries forward with Haberman sets $f(\tau) = (\tau + 1)$, when $\tau = t-1$. So technically $f(\tau) = (\tau - 1)$.

Again, so I understand the intents here, but the notation is really confusing. Can anyone explain this notation a bit better or provide a better/clearer way to solve this same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to have $t^2 H(t - 1) = f(t - c) H(t - c)$. Thus, comparing the two expressions, we see that we must take $c = 1$ and $f(t - 1) = t^2$. Note that $f(t) \neq t^2$. Rather, $f(t)$ is defined so that $f(t - 1) = t^2$. To find $f(t)$, we must perform a substitution. We take $\tau = t - 1$ so that $t = \tau + 1$. Then, substituting the expressions involving $\tau$ above, we find $f(\tau) = (\tau + 1)^2$. Since this is true for all $\tau$, this is the same as saying $f(t) = (t + 1)^2$. In any case, you can check that
$$
f(t-1) = ((t - 1) +1)^2 = (t)^2 = t^2
$$
which was the property we wanted $f$ to have.

Hopefully, this is convincing, but even if it isn't, you can see that $f(t - 1) = t^2$ when we take $f(t) = (t + 1)^2$. This is the property we needed the function $f$ to have, so we are done.

I think the confusion here arises from the fact that we began by defining $f$ as a function such that $f(t - 1) = t^2$, when you are probably used to seeing $f(x) = $ "some expression involving $x$". There is no issue with writing $f(t - 1) = t^2$ as long as we check that $f$ is well defined and has the desired domain and range. It just means we have to do a little work to find out how to write $f(t)$ as an expression involving $t$.

Comment: Thanks @Charles, this does confirm some of the intuition. Yeah, I think what is confusing is that the function $f()$ is the same but we are just re-expressing the points that are at $t$ to be points that are at $t-1$. So that variable $t$ kinda has two different "offsets" for lack of a better term. I understand the intuition, but the notation was confusing the algebra. Thanks again for the explanation, this does help.

Comment: It's important to remember that a function $f : X \to Y$ is just a rule for sending things in $X$ to things in $Y$ (such that no thing in $X$ goes to two different things in $Y$). There are many valid ways to specify such a function $f$. For example, if $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $Y = \mathbb{N}$, we could write $f(n) = n + 1$, or, equivalently, $f(n - 1) = n$. We could even write $f(2n) = 2n + 1$ and $f(2n + 1) = 2n + 2$. Statements like $f(x) = $ "some expression involving $x$" are just a convenient way of expressing what $f$ does, but there are many ways to specify the action of a function.